# CWinAppEx class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how i can add CWinAppEx class in vc++ 6.0 dialog MFC ,because i want to handle application state.How should i get this class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, it's an MFC update class that only works with the MFC that comes with VS2008.